# What happens in memory when we have errors in the code?

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand what happens exactly in memory if I have a macro and a constant with the same name?

```c
#define pi 3,14
const int pi=3,14;
```

Comment: Nothing happens in memory since such code will not compile.

Comment: For a start, C uses `.` as the radix point in floating point constants.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to worry what happens in memory, which is totally irrelevant here, but you need to worry about what your compiler will do with this code.

Remember that macros defined with `#define` are textually substituted during the compilation process.

Imagine you have this code:

```
#define pi 3.14
const int pi=3.14;
```

The preprocessor will replace `pi` with `3.14` due to the `#define pi 3.14`.

Therefore the compiler will actually see this:

```
const int 3.14=3.14;
```

And you'll get a compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

Define statement will replace `pi` with `3,14`.
So, your code will look like:

```c
const int 3,14=3,14;
```

Obviously, it will not work.